# JS array is not send to python script with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, python-2.7

An idea is to send `JS` array which contains of HTML element ids to python script using `AJAX`. I have gone through multiple examples, on Stackoverflow as well but none of them worked so far.

My `JS` function is:

```
function callpc1() {
    var pcimages = document.querySelectorAll('.pcpics');
    test = [];
    test[0] = pcimages[0].id;
    test[1] = pcimages[1].id;
    test[2] = pcimages[2].id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/~.../pcmove1.py",
        data: {
            test:test
        },
    });
}
```

Problem is python script gets no array data and variable remains empty on python side
On python side I use `getvalue` method. I assume an error is with `data:` definition. And I would to avoid using `JSON`
Please give a hint of what is wrongly defined here?

Edit

---

Code on python side

```
import cgi
page = cgi.FieldStorage()
listed =  page.getvalue('test', "unsuccess")
results = open("test.txt", "aw")
results.write (listed)
results.close()
```

Comment: What's the code on the Python side?

Comment: @Ouroborus I edited my question, added python code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `cgi` module does processing that isn't appropriate for submitted JSON data. Specifically, content of a POST request is provided to a CGI module on `stdin` and `cgi.FieldStorage()` reads that and tries to convert it into something useful but assumes a normal form submission. Other data is provided as environment variables.

Adjusting your example, you may be able to get your post data as a Python object like this:

```
import sys, os
import json

length = os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]
raw = sys.stdin.read(length)
data = json.loads(raw)
# Now we have a Python object representing the JSON data

# Convert the Python object back into a JSON formatted string
# and save to file
results = open("test.txt", "aw")
results.write(json.dumps(data))
results.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

In the AJAX Post method, you should send test as a JSON, try this before making the Post method:

```
obj = JSON.stringify(test);
```

And then change your data parameter with:

```
"data": obj
```

It should work.

Comment: OP is using jQuery. jQuery handles that automatically.

Comment: If you serialize to json you have to change default `contentType` and also be expecting json in request body at server. This answer is incomplete and misleading